# Split Values and Units using Jquery, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the values be like 10 #/mm3, and i want to split those as 10 and #/mm3 by value and unit respectively using jquery or Javascript, i tried to split it in java but i need it in client side.

```
10|mm
```

Comment: `str.split(" ");` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually it may or may not have the space,dynamically loaded value from another app, am invoking that one to my space,

Comment: It will be like 7.24X10^6, and i have to split it by 7.24 into a column and X10^6 into another column to store it into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it now

```js
var str = "51.400000000000006 % S*";
var val = str.search(/[%|X|-|+]/);
console.log(str.substr(0, val));
console.log(str.substr(val));

var str1 = "7.24X10^6";
var val = str1.search(/[%|X|-|+]/);
console.log(str1.substr(0, val));
console.log(str1.substr(val));
```

Comment: Some values will be like 51.400000000000006 %     S*, in this i need to split 51.400000000000006 as value and the rest of the  %     S* as unit

Comment: but how you find the split the string to perticuler position

Comment: Yes that is what my task have to do, there was no explanation on how the unit value should be, so shall we try any regexp like functions to separate those numerals and units, Help is appreciated..

Comment: your unit separate using %, x  , or other which symbol

Comment: Now i can find, every unit must be separated by a space with the numerals , so can we able to separate using the first space character on this string, like  51.400000000000006 % S* space is there between 6 and %,

Comment: Yes i got it by str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')); and units by str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1);

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is a way to split by the `X` character, but retain that character when split. You can achieve this by replacing the `X` with `,X` and then splitting by the `,`.

```js
var string = "7.24X10^6";
string = string.replace("X", ",X");
string = string.split(",");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: thanks for the response we are heading towards the alternate ideas, kindly follow the above comments